# jsplumb add elements, container draggable, elements not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb and trying to have a scenario such that when a user click button, 4 elements are created and are connectable using jsplumb.
I am trying to make the container draggable, not the elements that are connectable.

in my fiddle. i want the grey area box (id = container_1) to be draggable.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k97nL1fh/1/)

```
var a = 0;
var field = "";

$('#addField').click(function(){
    a++;

    var container = "<div class='container' id='container_"+a+"'></div>";

    $('#body').append(container);

    for (i=1;i<=9;i++){

        field = '<div class="item" id="entry_'+a+'_action_'+i+'">Text</div>';   
        $("#container_"+a).append(field);

            jsPlumb.ready(function() {

                var id = 'entry_'+a+'_action_'+i;

                jsPlumb.makeSource($('#'+id), {
                    connector: 'StateMachine'
                });

                jsPlumb.makeTarget($('#'+id), {
                    anchor: 'Right'
                });
            });
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom jquery draggable:

```
$('#container_'+a).draggable({ 
    drag:function(event){
            jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
    }
```

});

kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2905527/pruthvi-bharadwaj